# context preprocessors - global name 'user' is not defined

Tags: django

I have this error:

> global name 'user' is not defined

What am I doing wrong and how to correct it?

**context_processors.py**

```
from content.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def your_earned(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        ecredit = UserEarned.objects.get(user=user)
        if ecredit.exists():
            return {'ecredit': ecredit}
        else:
            ecredit = '0'
            return {'ecredit':ecredit}
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean `request.user`

```
ecredit = UserEarned.objects.get(user=user)
#                                     ^^^^ here
```